# Uploading Django to Ionos

Tags: django

I finished my first Django app and I want to upload it online on my domain with a server hosted by Ionos. But I really can't figure it out.
NOTE: settings.py is configured for production, I guess.

On my website by default, I have this "log" folder with different files in it:
[image]

Then I uploaded just simply my Django website (the content of the project folder) and so when I type in my domain I get 403 Forbidden Error.

So what I tried to do in order to understand better, is that I tried to upload a simple index.html file, and as expected it worked. Then I uploaded an index.html file inside a folder and so I got the same error. It may be this?

I really can't get my head around it so any help is hugely appreciated!

Comment: I'm also trying to upload django project to ionos vps. Any chance that you've solved this?

Comment: @Freemium at the end I used digital ocean, way easier. Other alternatives could be also AWS